# How can I fix Xcode ignoring the Prefix.pch file?

Tags: xcode4.5, prefix

Here is my problem: Xcode 4.5.2 has started ignoring the default Prefix.pch file while working in the editor, making the editor itself impossible to use (it doesn't recognize any more my classes and protocols imported in the Prefix.pch file), but I can correctly run my project in the simulator. The editor shows a bunch of errors, but it runs the project without problems, the error count drops to zero and after the projects has finished launching on the simulator the error count grows again.

Do you know how to fix this?